# Has anyone built ZBar using the Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate ZBar in my Android app but I cannot build the native library.
I was wondering if anyone did this before and is willing to share it with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just looking for something similar and came across this:

http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/?p=139

I don't know if it will help but it looks like it's what you're trying to do.  Hope it helps.

Comment: wow!...as I can see this is a new post. I remember I searched everywere when I posted the question. I managed to do that by myself but thanks anyway..there might be other people who got this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is old but the android SDK is available by ZBar: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/