# Barcode scanner application which sends result to a PHP application

Tags: php, android, ios, barcode-scanner

I'm not sure that this is the right place to ask this, but I'm going to give it a try. I'm looking for an application that can read a barcode and then send the code to another application. The second application is a PHP one, an e-commerce website. The first application, the one that reads the code, can also be an iOS or Android application, I don't mind.

Long story short I need an application that scans a barcode and then sends the result to a PHP application.

Did any of you happen to use something like this before?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for an _already built_ application, or is your intention to build it yourself? Reason being if you're looking for an already built app, StackOverflow most likely isn't the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Sorceforge project: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

It's an open library to read and parse barcodes. They also offer APIs for iOS/Linux.

See the discussions about **Android support** here http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/664596/topic/3750726 and [Has anyone built ZBar using the Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469461/has-anyone-built-zbar-using-the-android-ndk)